# SQL - SELECT statement precedence (Query vs. Sub-Query)

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I am wondering if someone can help me understand why the Sub-Query's SELECT statement ended up producing the column name 'Code' vs. the initial SELECT statement call 'local_name' in the below screenshot. Thank you[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the (ancient) pre-ISO syntax for `JOINs`. If you rewrite your query to use explicit `JOINs` you'll see what's going on.

Comment: I just realised you're folowing instructions from an online course for SQL... and the course is instructing you to use the old-style JOINs. Gah! That's horrible. You should stop taking **bad lessons** from that site and demand a refund!

Comment: AFAIK, the two column names should be `local_name` and `lang_num` ... I suspect the tool you are using has some quirks.

Comment: The sql tool running the query pick up the name/field wrongly I believe

Comment: Oof, bad class, I'd find a different resource for learning sql.